# ActionBarSherlock theme color

Tags: android, colors, themes, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I wish to replace red color to the default color of ActionBarSherlock, i search but don't know what to insert it the style.xml, below is my code:

```
<style name="Theme.Red" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light">
    <!-- what should i insert here? -->
</style>
```

What should i need to do if i want to change the color of the green highlight area? The whole bar, not the title only.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you want a red action bar?

```
<style name="Theme.Red" parent="Theme.Sherlock">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/RedActionBar</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/RedActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="RedActionBar" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">#f00</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Yes, thanks for your help. I think i should take some time on the android theme.